# How do I detect when the user is actively scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-events

My page has a scrollable area which contains a number of elements. Each element triggers a function when hovered over.

My issue is that if the user scrolls up or down with their mousewheel, the function triggers for every element that the cursor passes over as the area scrolls by underneath.

Is there a way that I can have the function trigger on hover only if the user is not actively scrolling?

jQuery's built-in `.scroll()` doesn't seem to be what I need, since the scroll event is triggered only when a scroll starts. I need to know if the scroll is "in progress" so to speak.

---

UPDATE: Here's my current code:

```
$container.find('div.item').each(function(i, e){
     $(e).hover(
          function(){
               $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
               // other functions here
          },
          function(){
               $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
          }
     );
});
```

So what I want to do is disable everything in `.hover()` if the user is currently scrolling the page.

Comment: Can we do this on touchpad scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `setTimeout` with a fair time on `mouseenter` and then `clearTimeout` on `mouseleave`, which would create an *small delay on the hovers*, so the hover only would trigger when the user holds his mouse over the element for the set time.

This would **hopefully** minimize your scrolling problem. There might be a better solution than this, but it was the first thing I thought of.

**EDIT**

Wrote this example quickly, should work fine:

```
$(function() {
    "use strict";
    var $container = $("#container"),
        timeout, self;

    $container.find("div").each(function() {
        $(this).hover(
            function() {
                self = this;
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $(self).css({
                        width : 500,
                        height: 500
                    });
                }, 500);
            },
            function() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                $(this).css({
                    width : 300,
                    height: 300
                });
            }
        );
    });
});
```

For a demo go to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/tVRwm/1/

It's up to you how much of an delay you want, I used 500ms.

**NOTE**

The `.each()` is not needed, you could call the `.hover()` on the `div` collection right away. I included `.each()` because I don't know if you want to do more than just binding the hover event.

Comment: Can this work in conjunction with jQuery's `.hover()`? See the update to my question.

Comment: @daGUY Surely can, see my updated post. Just implement that in your code.

Comment: That doesn't work with my code - maybe something to do with the `.each()`? After the delay, instead of the class toggling, I get: `TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'c.top')`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ga6z2/ The class doesn't toggle at all until after I mouseout of the element. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @daGUY Updated my post again, just go through it again. I'll check your fiddle right now.

Comment: @daGUY Updated you fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/ga6z2/1/. It was the `toggleClass` that was the problem. Changed to `addClass` and `removeClass`

Comment: @sQVe That was it! Thank you! This doesn't technically answer my question (detecting whether the user is scrolling), but it does effectively solve the problem (avoiding the hover triggering while a scroll is in progress).

Comment: can we do this on touch pad scroll?